# Python: Discrepancy in output values

Tags: python, numpy, math, output, primes

I'm following 3Blue1Brown's online Youtube video found here: [Youtube:3Blue1Brown](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4PDoT7jtxmw) and I'm using his implementation of finding prime numbers. You can see the program and the first set of his outputs @1:10 in the video.

Now, he's using Python v.3.7.0 and I'm using Python v.3.7.4. I have Numpy installed and my interpreter is integrated into Window's command prompt. I'm not creating an actual Python file, I'm just running the code straight within Python's interpreter.

Here is a copy of the entire command prompt's output for both the program and my results...

```
C:\Users\skilz99>python
Python 3.7.4 (tags/v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 20:34:20) [MSC v.1916 64 bit
(AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import math
>>>
>>> def get_primes(n_min, n_max):
...     result = []
...     for x in range(max(n_min, 2), n_max):
...         has_factor = False
...         for p in range(2, int(np.sqrt(x)) + 1):
...             if x % p == 0:
...                 has_factor = True
...                 break
...             if not has_factor:
...                 result.append(x)
...     return result
...
>>> get_primes(0,50)
[5, 7, 9, 11, 11, 13, 13, 15, 17, 17, 17, 19, 19, 19, 21, 23, 23, 23, 25, 25, 25
, 27, 29, 29, 29, 29, 31, 31, 31, 31, 33, 35, 35, 35, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 39, 41
, 41, 41, 41, 41, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 45, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49
]
>>>
```

Why am I getting completely different results than he is? I don't know if it's because of a different version of Python, or if the version of Numpy he's using is different than mine. But I'd like to think that a simple program like this should yield the same results.

Comment: After looking closer at the code, I think it might be due to an indentation error. Python isn't detecting it as an error since it is still valid Python code but do to the wrong indentation... I think it is parsing the code improperly and giving me undesirable results... I'll make the necessary edits and see if it fixes my problem!

Comment: shouldn't this part `if not has_factor:` be outside the inner loop?

Comment: I had mentioned improper indentation, I typed the program again with the proper indentation, and I'm getting the correct values. Yes, it should be a part of the outer loop but outside of the inner loop! It wasn't until after I posted this question that it started to stick out at me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the code you're trying to write is:

```py
import numpy as np
import math
def get_primes(n_min, n_max):
    result = []
    for x in range(max(n_min, 2), n_max):
        has_factor = False
        for p in range(2, int(np.sqrt(x)) + 1):
            if x % p == 0:
                has_factor = True
                break
        if not has_factor:
            result.append(x)
    return result
get_primes(0,50)
```

The problem was the second if statement where it is decided if `x` should or not be appended to the `result` list.

`x` should only be appended once per iteration so the if statement should be on the outer loop, where its value is decided.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed the improper indentation after I posted the question... I was staring at it for over 15 minutes and it was getting to me... So I asked here, then after I posted it, I noticed the improper indentation... I'm just more used to the C/C++ languages with scoped blocks...

Comment: Even though I figured it out just before you had posted this, I'll go ahead and accept your answer as it is the correct solution!

Comment: I'm sort of new to Python, I only started to learn it about 6months ago or so where I've been familiar with C/C++ for over 20 years... I don't use Python all that often, but I kind of like the language so I use it for simple things... If I want quick results from a simple function within a range of values, etc. but I mostly do 3D graphics type programming, therefore, I'm more akin to use C/C++ with DirectX, OpenGL, and Vulkan...

Comment: @FrancisCugler Thanks! It is nice to see people venturing on other programming languages, it takes us back to the times where we didn't know that much and made some silly mistakes, but that's what learning is about, making errors and fixing them, I feel this a lot when learning Haskell XD. Congratulations on your career, I'm an enthusiast of Computer Graphics, its a wonderful area. Keep up coding ;D

Comment: I started picking up Java - JavaScript lately too because I've been following Dan on youtube with his coding challenges... from the Coding Train... I'm also a little familiar with Assembly but I rarely use it unless if I'm trying to make specific C++ code blocks as efficient as possible by writing inline assembly for performance reasons... I don't just work with 3D graphics, I'm also learning about Hardware Emulation, Compiler Design, and ISA architecture down to both the logic level and electronic component levels. I'm great with math but I also like Physics!

Comment: With that being said, I like to learn about all layers of abstraction when it comes to Computers! I mean from the Chemistry and Physics that makes up the transitions all the way up to HTML...